# ElasticSearch query against 3 location fields?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is it possible with ElasticSearch to query against three different location fields? This would be with geo-location search. Only one of the three fields would need to match the queried location for the document to be a match.

If possible, a Java example would be a bonus.

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean query or [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query.html) to combine two or more (geo) filters